# change or remove password on bootup

Tags: password

I just bought a used macbook (osx 10.8), and when i started it up there was a disk password. The former owner gave me the password but i would like to remove it, or at least change it. How can I? Is this something from "file vault"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's file vault.

To remove file vault protection:

1) Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click Security & Privacy, and then click FileVault.
2) Click the lock to unlock the preferences pane, and then enter an administrator name and password.
3) Click Turn Off FileVault.
4) Click Turn Off Encryption.

Then if you want to re-enable it, you can choose your own password.

Comment: Some approaches to FileVault 2 produce a logical volume that is not revertible. But for a Mac about which little is known, this answer is the best guess.